# Unable to trap signals in docker entrypoint script

Tags: docker, wait, tomcat9, sigterm, bash-trap

I have a docker entrypoint script that is supposed to trap signals sent to processes in the container. The main application is tomcat - java process embedded in the docker-entrypoint.sh which is passed to dumb-init. The process mapping in the container looks like so:

```
root@mycontainer:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/datarouter-example# ps -ef
    UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
    root         1     0  0 05:21 ?        00:00:00 dumb-init -- /docker-entrypoint.sh
    root         6     1  0 05:21 ?        00:00:00 bash /docker-entrypoint.sh
    root        14     6  1 05:21 ?        00:08:57 /jdk-13.0.1/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=....
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-13 as maven_builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN ["mvn","clean","install","-T","2C","-DskipTests=true"]


FROM tomcat:9.0.31-jdk13-openjdk-buster

ARG dumbInitVersion='1.2.2'

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        sudo \
        wget \
        dpkg-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ARG webappDir
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/$webappDir/
ENV CATALINA_OUT $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out
ENV CATALINA_PID $CATALINA_HOME/catalina.pid
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
COPY --from=maven_builder /app/target/datarouter-example $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/$webappDir/

RUN wget https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v"$dumbInitVersion"/dumb-init_"$dumbInitVersion"_amd64.deb; \
    dpkg -i dumb-init_*.deb; \
    rm dumb-init_*.deb

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--", "/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

And this is the simplified docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
        #!/usr/bin/env bash

        start(){
                echo "$(date +'%F %T,%3N') Starting tomcat..." >> "$CATALINA_OUT"
                catalina.sh start && tail -f "$CATALINA_OUT"
        }

        stop(){
                echo "$(date +'%F %T,%3N') starting stop" >> "$CATALINA_OUT"

   # some fancy shutdown logic, e.g. calling our application's shutdown endpoint to cleanup (does not stop tomcat)

                echo "$(date +'%F %T,%3N') Stopping tomcat..." >> "$CATALINA_OUT"
                catalina.sh stop  >> "$CATALINA_OUT"

                wait $(cat "${CATALINA_PID}")

                tailId=$(pgrep tail)
                if [[ -n "$tailId" ]]; then
                        kill "$tailId"
                fi
                exit
        }

        trap stop SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGHUP SIGTERM

    start
```

Now the issue.
Every time a `docker stop` command or a `kill 1` from inside the container is issued, the java application would be sent a signal and start to shutdown first before the `stop` function even gets to the first line. I am sure because of the `Terminated` log:

```
Terminated
++ stop
+++ date '+%F %T,%3N'
++ echo '2020-03-13 14:34:54,480 starting stop'
```

and in catalina.out:

```
2020-03-12 04:08:27.079 INFO [Thread-13] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
2020-03-12 04:08:27,079 starting stop
2020-03-12 04:08:27.085 INFO [Thread-13] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]
2020-03-12 04:08:27.090 INFO [Thread-13] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-8443"]
2020-03-12 04:08:27.096 INFO [Thread-13] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
......
```

I'm really confused of why this is happening and how to fix this so that `catalina.sh stop` gets to be executed.

Comment: Could you post the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Updated to include the Dockerfile. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying a few changes, the following script traps the SIGTERM and executes the expected steps.

Changes from original docker-entrypoint, Dockerfile:

- Switched from dumb-init to tini, just to try it out.
- Switched from catalina start to catalin run and putting it in background myself and waiting on it
- Removed the tail process

I think the tail is what was causing the original described behaviour. The bigest downside of the new entrypoint script is that I lost the container logs when running `docker logs ...`. Since we bind mount the logs directory, we're still able to get the logs, but will be investigating further to get back `docker logs ...`

I'm still in search for a nicer solution if anyone has an advice or other solutions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap stop SIGTERM SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGHUP ERR

start(){
   local catalinaPid

   touch "${CATALINA_PID}"
   catalina.sh run >> ${CATALINA_OUT} 2>&1 &
   catalinaPid=$!
   echo "$catalinaPid" > "${CATALINA_PID}"

   wait "$catalinaPid"
}

stop(){
   echo "$(date +'%F %T,%3N') starting stop" >> "$CATALINA_OUT"

   # some fancy shutdown logic, e.g. calling our application's shutdown endpoint to cleanup (does not stop tomcat)

   echo "$(date +'%F %T,%3N') Stopping tomcat..." >> "$CATALINA_OUT"
   catalina.sh stop 20 >> "$CATALINA_OUT"

   wait $(cat "${CATALINA_PID}")

   exit
}

start
```

Comment: Are you still searching for a better solution or did you maybe find one?
I have the same needs. My solution is to source catalina.sh "start" und then follow log until tomcat is started: `timeout 30 tail -F $CATALINA_OUT | sed '/Server startup in/ q'`

Comment: With a few minor changes, it actually works great, been using it since March. I posted it here: https://github.com/Me-ion/tomcat_docker_entrypoint with some description. Since it worked so well, we adapted it for nodejs apps too. The key is that the process (application) needs to run as a background process